# Node Express Server : How to serve HTML file properly (scripts and css included) ? (csp, relative path and thing like that)

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, content-security-policy

(I know this question have been asked many times in many form, but I tried a lot of solution and none work the way it should.. So maybe a solution adapted to my work would help me understand.)

Here is the [structure of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SzZL.jpg).

Here is the index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default ">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <script src="../node_modules//bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the server/app.js. I let the res.sendFile(); empty on purpose.

```
//export used
var express = require('express'),
    url = require("url"),  
    path = require("path"),  
    fs = require("fs");

const _port = 3000
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile();
});

app.listen(_port, function() { console.log('listening port '+_port+"\n__dirname : "+__dirname)});
```

The purpose of the server for now is just to send the index.html, that is one level up in the public folder. when a request in made to '/'. and I CAN'T DO IIIITT,
for several reason:
-I tried to use helmet to workaround Content Security Policy.
-I tried to use the static middleware to do stuff..
-I tried to use the path.join / resolve

So is there anyone who can explain somehow how to send this public/index.html file with the bootstrap scripts/css working ?

Have a nice day

---

Edit:

Here is the new app.js, it render the index.html thanks to the express.static but bootstrap css/scripts are not rendered :

```js
//export used
var express = require('express'),
    url = require("url"),  
    path = require("path"),  
    fs = require("fs");

const _port = 3000
var app = express();



app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/..', 'public')));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile('../public/index.html',{root: __dirname});
});
app.listen(_port, function() { console.log('listening port '+_port+"\n__dirname : "+__dirname)});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add static middleware just after defining your app and before other routings because **it is recommended to put static middleware first**.

**Use the path module to join the paths** since it helps to avoid issues
of operating systems working differently with slashes and backslashes.

`app.use( '/' , express.static(path.join(__dirname ,'..' ,'public'));`

By doing this, you can serve all your static files in the public directory including scripts and css.

Comment: use this `path.join(__dirname ,'/..' ,'public')`

Comment: It worked !! Thanks, here is the code I used :

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/..', 'public')));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile('../public/index.html',{root: __dirname});
});

But now the page doesnt render bootstrap script and css ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using express, then you shouldn't serve single file instead you can make a static folder where all your js and css lies and you can serve that whole folder and use angular for routing.

Here is sample code:

```
var express = require('express'),
    url = require("url"),  
    path = require("path"),  
    fs = require("fs");

const _port = 3000
var app = express();

app.use('/',express.static(__dirname+'public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.listen(_port, function() { console.log('listening port '+_port+"\n__dirname : "+__dirname)});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but __dirname end with /server, I have to go one level up to target public and when i do : express.static(__dirname+'../public'), it doesnt work